# Get data from firebase with Result of LiveData in viewmodel

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I want to get 2 objects from firebase and I want to display combine results on the Recyclerview using viewmodel. I have created a viewmodel that gets the one object from firebase and based on id from this object I want to get the other object and update the ui.
some code of view model class

```
  private static final DatabaseReference POST_REF =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Post");

private final FirebaseQueryLiveData liveData = new 
FirebaseQueryLiveData(POST_REF);
 @NonNull
public LiveData<DataSnapshot> getDataSnapshotLiveData() {

    return liveData;

}
```

FirebaseQueryLiveData class

```
private final MyValueEventListener listener = new MyValueEventListener();


public FirebaseQueryLiveData(DatabaseReference ref) {
    this.query = ref;
}

@Override
protected void onActive() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActive");
    query.addValueEventListener(listener);
}

@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onInactive");
    query.removeEventListener(listener);
}
```

How to get the second object from firebase using the result of first and notify the livedata about it

First object is post of users and second object is userinfo . I want to display combine result on Ui.

DataBase Structure I Want to get post and based on ids in post I want to get userdetails
    [image]

Comment: Add the complete code, database structure and model class @RohanSharma

Comment: @Raj I have edited the question

Comment: Did u later solve this??

Answer (score -1):

I think step# 5 in [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/#0) is the answer to your problem.
Here you can update UI once data in firebase changes.

Comment: I dont think so they are not using livedata or viemodels

Comment: To update UI using viewmodels and livedata you have to use room persistent library of android.   https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-app-with-arch-components/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Comment: I want to get results from both post and user model and update livedata object with it. That is my main concern how to do it ?